ACPI ASL/AML: Get GPIOs and LEDs working withing linux-drivers
I have a GPIO-Expander (PCF8574) in my x86-based System which is connected to the SMBus.

GPIO0-3 are used as GPIOs.
GPIO4-7 are used to controll LEDs.

To get it to work and later hopefully into the BIOS/EFI I use ACPI ASL.
Currently I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS with HWE Kernel 6.5.0-14
I searched a lot like this or this thread and also asked chatgpt for help but yeaaaaah... that didnt work either :D
I'm currently stuck with following ASL, which almost work but as I try to load it, I receive this:
[   48.736439] ACPI: Host-directed Dynamic ACPI Table Load:
[   48.736468] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8A7BCF287800 000435 (v01 VENDOR EXPANDER 00000001 INTL 20200925)
[   48.747914] pcf857x i2c-PRP0001:03: probed
[   48.748820] leds-gpio: probe of PRP0001:04 failed with error -16

The GPIOs are recognized via gpioinfo/gpiodetect, are controllable and named properly.
-16 would mean device or resource busy. It seems that the led-drivers says the resource is busy, but I thought that the leds-gpio driver will use the provided gpios not the i2c-resource. Am I wrong? Is it possible to "split" a gpio-expander like this?
My ASL:
DefinitionBlock ("expander.aml", "SSDT", 1, "VENDOR", "EXPANDER", 0x00000001)
{
    External (\_SB.PC00.SBUS, DeviceObj) 

    Scope (\_SB.PC00.SBUS)  // Scope of the I2C controller
    {
        Device (EXIO)  // GPIO expander device
        {
            Name (_HID, "PRP0001")  // Hardware ID
            Name (_DDN, "GPIO-Expander")
            Name (_UID, 3)     // Unique ID
            Name (_CID, "nxp,pcf8574")
            Name (_DSD, Package ()
            {
                ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                Package () {
                    Package () { "compatible", Package() { "nxp,pcf8574" } },
                    Package () { "gpio-line-names", Package () {
                        "SATA1-Status",
                        "SATA1-Hotplug",
                        "SATA2-Status",
                        "SATA2-Hotplug",
                        }
                    },
                }
            })

            Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
                I2CSerialBusV2 (
                    0x21,                        // SlaveAddress
                    ControllerInitiated,         // SlaveMode
                    100000,                      // ConnectionSpeed
                    AddressingMode7Bit,          // AddressingMode
                    "\\_SB.PC00.SBUS",           // ResourceSource
                    0x00,                        // ResourceSourceIndex
                    ResourceConsumer,            // ResourceUsage
                    ,                            // DescriptorName
                    Exclusive                    // ShareType
                                                 // VendorData
                )
            })

            Method (_STA, 0, NotSerialized)
            {
                Return (0x0F)
            }
        }

        Device (LEDS)
        {
            Name (_HID, "PRP0001")
            Name (_DDN, "GPIO LEDs device")
            Name (_UID, 3)
            Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
                GpioIo (
                    Exclusive,                  // Not shared
                    PullNone,                   // Default off
                    0,                          // Debounce timeout
                    0,                          // Drive strength
                    IoRestrictionOutputOnly,    // Only used as output
                    "\\_SB.PC00.SBUS.EXIO",     // GPIO controller
                    0)                          // Must be 0
                {
                    4,  // LED1
                    5,  // LED2
                    6,  // LED3
                    7,  // LED4                        
                }
            })
            
            Name (_DSD, Package () {
                ToUUID("dbb8e3e6-5886-4ba6-8795-1319f52a966b"),
                Package () {
                    Package () { "led-4", "LED0" },
                    Package () { "led-5", "LED1" },
                    Package () { "led-6", "LED2" },
                    Package () { "led-7", "LED3" },
                },
                
                ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                Package () {
                    Package () { "compatible", Package() { "gpio-leds" } },
                },
            })
            
            Name (LED0, Package () {
                ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                Package () {
                    Package () { "label", "led-4" },
                    Package () { "led-max-microamp", 10000 },
                    Package () { "default-state", "off"},
                    Package () { "gpios", Package () {^LEDS, 0, 0, 1}},
                }
            })
            
            Name (LED1, Package () {
                ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                Package () {
                    Package () { "label", "led-5" },
                    Package () { "led-max-microamp", 10000 },
                    Package () { "default-state", "off"},
                    Package () { "gpios", Package () {^LEDS, 0, 1, 1}},
                }
            })
            
            Name (LED2, Package () {
                ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                Package () {
                    Package () { "label", "led-6" },
                    Package () { "led-max-microamp", 10000 },
                    Package () { "default-state", "off"},
                    Package () { "gpios", Package () {^LEDS, 0, 2, 1}},
                }
            })
            
            Name (LED3, Package () {
                ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                Package () {
                    Package () { "label", "led-7" },
                    Package () { "led-max-microamp", 10000 },
                    Package () { "default-state", "off"},
                    Package () { "gpios", Package () {^LEDS, 0, 3, 1}},
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

EDIT: I changed the LED pin within their property to the corresponding index number, the problem is solved
Big thanks to 0andriy who pointed this out.

Quickly found mistake (may be not the only one) is that you supplied the same GPIO for all LEDs. How is it supposed to work?! See an example form meta-acpi project: https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi/blob/master/recipes-bsp/acpi-tables/samples/minnowboard/leds.asl.

Thanks for your comment, I dont really see that. Within the Device(EXIO) I declared 4 GPIO Pins, named SATA... and within Device(LEDS) the last four Pins 4-7 (LED0-LED3) shall be used as LEDs? Or do i see something wrong? :D

Ah within the LEDx last packages. :) Thanks, I fixed that, but it didnt solve the problem

While at it, you don't need _CID in EXIO. It's confusing for PRP0001 cases.

Ah, of course it won't work, you need to suply index in _CRS in the Package(), they should be from 0 to 3, and not from 4 to 7.  First what you may try is to leave only a single LED (in ASL) for now and see that it works, then add the rest. Again, see the above link to meta-acpi project. It has plenty of tested examples (most recent ones for Intel Edison board).

Ha it works! I doublechecked the meta-acpi example and i mistook the GPIO Numbers, its not the hardware-pin but the position in the GPIO-Expanders list of pins :) Thank you so much!

Thanks to 0andriy who pointed out the problems:

I assigned all LEDs to the same index/pin.
I assigned the LEDs to their "Hardware-Pin" and not the index of the GpioIo-Property

After changing the LEDs to their corresponding Indexes, it worked. :)
Name (LED0, Package () {
    [...]
    Package () { "gpios", Package () {^LEDS, 0, 0, 1}},
    [...]
})
Name (LED1, Package () {
    [...]
    Package () { "gpios", Package () {^LEDS, 0, 1, 1}},
    [...]
})
Name (LED2, Package () {
    [...]
    Package () { "gpios", Package () {^LEDS, 0, 2, 1}},
    [...]
})
Name (LED3, Package () {
    [...]
    Package () { "gpios", Package () {^LEDS, 0, 3, 1}},
    [...]
})

In hindsight it totally made sense that the device is responsing with busy, due to the fact that I assigned four LEDs to the same GPIO...

You should not have edited your original question and fixed it. So, that people can understand the difference between the wrong and right one.
